# How can paypal fund be split in various vandor account?

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have a wordpress site which payment methods are PayPal Payouts and stripe connect.stripe and PayPal work correctly however there is a small problem. The funds paid should be split. 5.5% to admin and 94.5% to vendors. Now all of the funds are going to admin and not vendors. I need help to configure

Comment: Are you working with any specific platform (ie. WordPress)?  If so, are you working with a specific plugin like Dokan or WC Vendors?

Comment: Yes, I work in wordpress, woocommerce platform. Which plugin can I used for split. transection .The funds paid should be split. 5.5% to admin and 94.5% to vendors. Now all of the funds are going to admin and not vendors. Thanks